# Expo Push Notification Unable to retrieve the FCM server key for the recipient’s app. Make sure you have provided a server key as directed…

Tags: push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

SDK Version: 40
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android

I already have setted the expo push:android:show
error return me:

[Click to see error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMHPF.png)

If I click on button just have no returns

I’m just using the example code available on Push Notifications Overview - Expo Documentation 1

setted expo push:android:show and
fcm,firebase,push,google-services.json
look:

[Cick to see what I setted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXyN7.png)

I installed the expo dependecies before expo ejected.
I setted the Firebase app name com.myname.testpush as the AndroidManifest package name as well.

```
“dependencies”: {
“expo”: “~40.0.0”,
“expo-status-bar”: “~1.0.3”,
“react”: “16.13.1”,
“react-dom”: “16.13.1”,
“react-native”: “~0.63.4”,
“react-native-web”: “~0.13.12”,
“expo-notifications”: “~0.8.2”,
“expo-permissions”: “~10.0.0”,
“expo-splash-screen”: “~0.8.1”,
“expo-task-manager”: “~8.5.0”,
“expo-updates”: “~0.4.0”,
“expo-constants”: “~9.3.0”,
“@react-native-firebase/app”: “^10.5.0”,
“react-native-gesture-handler”: “~1.8.0”,
“react-native-reanimated”: “~1.13.0”,
“react-native-screens”: “~2.15.0”,
“react-native-unimodules”: “~0.12.0”
},
“devDependencies”: {
“@babel/core”: “~7.9.0”,
“babel-jest”: “~25.2.6”,
“jest”: “~25.2.6”,
“react-test-renderer”: “~16.13.1”
},
```

posted on expo as well: https://forums.expo.io/t/push-notification-unable-to-retrieve-the-fcm-server-key-for-the-recipients-app-make-sure-you-have-provided-a-server-key-as-directed/48529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved on Expo Forum (https://forums.expo.io/t/push-notification-unable-to-retrieve-the-fcm-server-key-for-the-recipients-app-make-sure-you-have-provided-a-server-key-as-directed/48529/2)

@adamjnav creating a new project I could see that I forgot of set my **experienceId: "@myexpouser/myproject"**
and my app.json android: { …, **“useNextNotificationsApi”: true,** “adaptiveIcon”:"… }

Comment: ++ experienceid can be retrived from import Constants from "expo-constants";
const experienceId = Constants.manifest.id;

Answer (score 4):

expo push:android:show (it wasn't configured for me)

then expo push:android:upload --api-key  , replacing with the string you just copied. (to get the token look at https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/#uploading-server-credentials)

Answer (score 1):

Adding on here: I was totally confused by firebase's new cloud messaging api and the documentation.

You have to use firebase legacy cloud messaging to get a Server Key. Other than that - documentation and uploading that server key worked great as described by others.
Screenshot showing:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add FCM server key to expo directly from EAS,

run command **eas credentials** > Android > Push Notifications: Manage your FCM Api Key > Paste Firebase server key

It will automatically add firebase server key to Expo and we can see it on portal as well