# There was an unknown error with the FCM server. See this error's details for more information

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to setup Push Notifications Setup and I have followed this documentation for the frontend and backend as well https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/.
I have created FCM for android and I have used the API server key in the google-service.json that firebase gave it to me to put it in the project.
When I created the apk(to test the notification) in my logs it showed me this error:

```
 [
  {
   id: 'c4b19090-cc75-482e-b194-a37647fd2af7',
     status: 'error',
    message: "There was an unknown error with the FCM server. See this error's details for more information.",
     messageEnum: null,
     messageParamValues: null,
     details: {
      error: 'ProviderError',
       errorCodeEnum: 1,
      fault: 'fcm',
      fcm: [Object]
    }
   }
]
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Have you enabled google cloud messaging in your project and you need to use server key provided there. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72635592/8196025).

Comment: I have enabled google cloud messaging in my project and have used the server key as well, but still  this error is showed up.